# Stopped accessing the SD card on the camera from the Finder window

Tags: finder, photos, photos.app, camera, sd-card

I have gotten a new problem... Before it has been easy to access the SD card on my Canon camera using a USB cable connected to my Mac mini. The SD card has shown up as a new device on the the left hand side of the finder window and I have been able to select the images I want by drag and drop them directly into a file structure. However, now the Photo application starts directly as I connect the camera and want to import the images. I can see the images on the camera so the card and connection is obviously working but I can't see the SD card in the finder window. When I quit the Photo window I still can't see any connection in the finder window.

Thankful for any help on this.

Comment: What kind of updates have you installed before it stopped working as expected?

Comment: I dont know really... It was quite a time since I emptied the camera card. Now I have Catalina 10.15.7 installed.